# Cruise Control Build Strategy

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

We currently have CruiseControl.NET (v.1.6.7981.1) running on a 'development integration server.'  We have a number of separate .NET sites that operate under the same IIS site and therefore share a 'bin' folder.  This is the required setup due to the CMS implementation.

With a shared bin folder, an assembly change from one site could throw an error and affect all the other sites.

What we do is build and deploy the single site that we're currently working on to the integration environment and then spot-check the other sites to ensure they are still working.

In order to have more immediate feedback on the builds, we are looking at utilizing triggers to build all solutions at the time of a checkin of any solution.  Ideally, we would like to avoid having to edit each project's configuration when a new site is developed and brought into the integration environment.

Does this sound like a sound approach or is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about automating some of your ui tests, using something like browser stack or watin?

Comment: No, hadn't considered that yet.  I like that idea and will look into implementing something like that once we get our Cruise Control builds automated.